# htaccess regex - is there any way to capture encoded urls?

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I need to capture URLs that have any characters that could be encoded. For example +, {space}, [,] etc. I tired doing the following but did not work -

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^(.*)(\s|\+|\%)+(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /content/my-rewrite-redirect.php [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mydomain.com/content/$1$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mydomain.com/content/$1 [QSA,L]
```

(\s|+|\%) - tried this to capture space characters and any character that has been encoded in the URL but it does not capture URLs like - http://mydomain.com/vertical%5B1%5D.jpg

Thansk for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're running into is likely that URLs are decoded by Apache before getting to htaccess.  You should try instead of searching for encoded characters, to create a regex that searches for any characters that WOULD BE URL-encoded.

e.g.:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} [!@#$%^&*`~\(\)\\/\[\]\{\}\+]+
```

Of course, there will be many more characters that qualify... this is just an example

Comment: Thank you. Accepting your answer with a bit of modification that works for me, here is what I used -
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ["-\*]|\s|\+|,|[:->]|[\[-\^]|[{-~]